# MySQL in vmware virtual machine

Tags: mysql, vmware-esxi

What do you think about having MySQLd in vmware VM ? The problem is, we are having MySQL cluster on 2 nodes and it keeps on making the problems (auto-restarting ndbd, ndb_mgmt must be available etc). The performance is not that critical, as it is used mainly by VoIP PBX system.

Could you please give me some pros/cons about having it in the virtual machine that has HA enabled ?

Comment: How much data isn't written to disk? Whatever is queued up to be written but not flushed, I suppose. How much do you have queued at a given time?...I don't know.

Comment: Ok, nevermind the second question.

Comment: Are you saying you have a MySQL cluster where there are periodic failures of the services, and you're thinking of fixing it by migrating them to VM's?

Comment: No, simple architecture conversion from mysql cluster (ndbd)
 on bare-metal to mysqld in VM without clustering.

Comment: Well, if the question really is, "What do you think...", then I think it's nice. As Chopper said there's a small performance hit but if you're not pressing your current server, it shouldn't be a problem. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Ok thank you :) I was afraid that it is violating some best practices, for ex. mysql ndb cluster running in VM is not recommended at all...

Comment: @Mejmo, have you ever started something, then realised a little way down the line that it wasn't for you? if so how was that for you? did it hurt a little or a lot? has it put you off making changes in your life or did you learn that change can be great - opening new doors to amazing possibilities? if so do you have any unfulfilled dreams or ambitions? or do you want to do this kind of IT work forever?

Comment: Chopper, I'm not really quite sure, if I understand you .. why this question? :/

Comment: I just want all serverfault users to be happy and benefit the most they can in their lives by coming here, I guess I'm asking if you're happy in your job. The reason is that I'm not sure you love the job you have, I'm lucky, I love my job and that's because I'm super interested in it. I spend all my free time learning new stuff, speaking to others about all this IT stuff and I've developed skills in finding out the details I need to do my job, from the most basic to most complex research. I don't see you doing that, I may be wrong but it doesn't feel like you enjoy learning IT stuff too much.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, I'm appreciating it very much, especially from the expert like you. I will write you later.

Comment: Please understand that I'm not being horrible, I do care, I just worry that we're not seeing the expected 'growth' in your knowledge and skills that perhaps I'd expect by now (you've been on here a while now after all). You're clearly smart enough to ask these questions but as I say the rate of knowledge growth makes me suspicious of where your passions lie. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, well you've got a couple of things going on here.

- MySQL running in a VM will of course run a little slower than on bare-metal, especially if there's a lot of IO going on - there's no way around that, it's the cost of virtualisation. That said it may not be too bad, maybe only a ~3-5% CPU speed loss, ~3-7% memory speed loss and anywhere between 5% and 25% of IO performance drop based on the load, concurrency with other VMs and disk subsystem setup.
- HA makes no difference to this at all, literally none - all HA does is say that if a host goes off line your VMs will restart on another host. But nothing changes until one of your hosts falls over, nothing at all. Now if a host does fall over HA will restart the VMs on the other hosts, not this could mean that the working hosts would then have more load per host and thus the performance could drop overall but only for the time it takes for the failed host to recover and for you to manually or automatically (with DRS) reallocate your VMs across your hosts.

Hope this helps. By the way are you planning on working in your role on an ongoing basis?

Comment: Thank you Chopper. No this mustn't be done live, dumping and inserting into new architecture, that's all. I found a great tutorial for designing the disk subsystem for mysql http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2008/03/05/evaluating-io-subsystem-performance-for-mysql-needs/ , but how can I find out how many IOs my current mysql cluster is having ?

Answer (score 1):

We've had great success running a setup like this:

> node=1 -> ndb-MGM node (Bare Metal Server A)
>   node=2 -> NDB node (Bare Metal Server B)
>   node=3 -> NDB node (Bare Metal Server C)
>   node=4 -> mysql API node (in a VM)
>   node=5 -> mysql API node (in a VM)

This setup has ran without fault for two years now. We run about 30 queries per second during business hours without any data loss. We need the speed for processing phone calls. When someone dials a phone number, it has to be pretty much instant.